# Unity + arduino error: Specified port is not open

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino

I'm trying to get my arduino working with Unity but I keep getting errors about my port not being open.

Here's my Unity code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class movingTest : MonoBehaviour
{
SerialPort data_stream = new SerialPort("/dev/cu.usbmodem142401", 19200);
public string receivedstring;
public GameObject test_data;
public Rigidbody rb;
public float sensitivity = 0.01f;

public string[] datas;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    data_stream.Open();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    receivedstring = data_stream.ReadLine();

    string[] datas = receivedstring.Split(',');
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, float.Parse(datas[0])*sensitivity * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    rb.AddForce(float.Parse(datas[1]) * sensitivity * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

    transform.Rotate(0, float.Parse(datas[2]), 0);
}
}
```

It shows a red squiggly line under "using System.IO.Ports" (**The type of namespace name 'Ports' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**)

There's also another red squiggly line under "SerialPort" (**The type of namespace name 'SerialPort' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**)

My Api Compatibility is .NET Standard 2.0

When the game runs on Unity, the only error I get is "**Specified port is not open**".

Here's how my ports look like. Every youtube tutorial I watched had ports like "COM4" or something, while I get this weird **/dev/cu.usbmodem...** monstrosity. I think this is my main problem.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Arduino ports]

Comment: Are you sure thats the device name? It sounds awfully machine specific so likely wouldn’t work  on other machines

Comment: i literally dont know. I am using a Chinese arduino knockoff, so maybe that is the device's name?

Comment: Probably caused because it is not finding the System.IO.Ports assembly, check this link from the unity forums [System.IO.Ports missing for Unity with .NET 4.x](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1604233/systemioports-missing-for-unity-with-net-4x.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well the error is most probably due to [`System.IO.Ports`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport) is not part of `.NET Standard` but only in `.NET Framework`.

[image]

You want to chose

`API Compatibility Level` -> `4.x`

[image]

I wonder though how you run your game if you have compiler errors.

Comment: I changed my Api compatibility level to .NET 4.x now and I still get the red squiggly lines under the System.IO.Ports and SerialPort. However, when I press play, my Unity freezes and the only thing I can do is force quit it. Do I have to do something in Visual Studio, so VS knows i use .NET 4.x now?

Comment: OK, after deleting the code in the Update() function (except the receivedstring), the code runs but stills says that the specified port is not open

Comment: `receivedstring = data_stream.ReadLine();` is a **blocking** call which freezes the code until actually something was received